# Finding the probability that $6$ heads are obtained if a coin is tossed until there are $5$ tails

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed until $5$ tails. Find the probability of $6$ heads. 
I tried this way. 
$$P (X=11)=\binom{10}{4}\frac{1}{2^5} \frac{1}{2^6}$$
I'm not sure. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain your attempt more clearly? You have posted an unformatted equation with undefined variables.

Comment: The result looks fine to me. But how you define the random variable $X$?

Answer (score 2):

The last toss is the fifth $T$. For a win you therefore need exactly $6$ heads and $4$ tails in the first ten tosses, and then a $T$ to finish it up. The probability for the first to happen is ${10\choose4}\cdot2^{-10}$. When you have reached this point the probability that you get a $T$ in the next toss is ${1\over2}$. It follows that the probability $p$ of a win is given by $$p={10\choose4}\cdot2^{-11}=0.102539\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least $6$ heads in the first $10$ tosses.  Aside from an extra factor $\frac 12$ (the exponent $5$ should be $4$) you have computed the chance of exactly $6$ heads.